# ApplicationInsights - CustomProperties don't update between requests

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-application-insights

I want to report some properties via Azure-ApplicationInsights for each route like shown in the picture from below:  [image]

The problem is that even if I do a second call, on the same route or different route, those value don't change. Only at the third call the value is changed, but even then is not the current one. 
Example:

1. I do https://localhost:5001/api/testobject/**7**
   The "proprietate custom" = "valoare custom **7**"
2. I do https://localhost:5001/api/testobject/***8***
   The "proprietate custom" = "valoare custom ***7***"
3. I do https://localhost:5001/api/testobject/***9***
   The "proprietate custom" = "valoare custom ***8***"

Code behind looks like this:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class TestObjectController
{
    private TelemetryClient telemetryClient;

    public TestObjectController(TelemetryClient telemetryClient)
    {
        this.telemetryClient = telemetryClient;
    }

    // GET api/values/5
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public ActionResult<string> Get(int id)
    {
        telemetryClient.Context.Properties.Clear(); 
        telemetryClient.Context.GlobalProperties["TestObjectController"] = "nok";
        telemetryClient.Context.Properties["proprietate custom"] = $"valoare custom {id}";
        return "value";
    }
}
```

Any idea how to keep it accurate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@[Dmitry Matveev] thank you, but your suggestion partially works, but I was more interested to add certain information from the request content (e.g. tenant name). For this I ended up with adding information in HttpContext.Items and then access them via 'MyTelemetryInitializer' like explained in this link: https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-aspnetcore/wiki/Custom-Configuration#track-custom-traceeventmetric

Code that add info to the route:

```
    [HttpGet("{id}/details")]
    public ActionResult<string> GetDetails(int id)
    {
        HttpContext.Items.Add("custom property2", id);
        return "value";
    }
```

Part of the 'MyTelemetryInitializer' Initialize method:

```
    foreach (var prop in httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Items)
    {
        if (prop.Key is string)
            requestTelemetry.Context.GlobalProperties[prop.Key.ToString()] = prop.Value.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

`telemetryClient.Context.Properties` sets context on the Telemetry Client instance only. That means that several telemetry items may get created with the previous context before new one takes effect (if telemetry item is created before the context update).

This seems to be the case here - Request Telemetry item is created at the moment of the method invocation and only later inside the method the client is updated to have new context.

I'd suggest using `TelemetryInitializer` instead [to update the context on the level of the Telemetry Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-filtering-sampling#add-properties-itelemetryinitializer) but not Telemetry Client:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Channel;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DataContracts;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility;

namespace MvcWebRole.Telemetry
{
  /*
   * Custom TelemetryInitializer that overrides the default SDK
   * behavior of treating response codes >= 400 as failed requests
   *
   */
  public class MyTelemetryInitializer : ITelemetryInitializer
  {
    public void Initialize(ITelemetry telemetry)
    {
        var requestTelemetry = telemetry as RequestTelemetry;
        // Is this a TrackRequest() ?
        if (requestTelemetry == null) return;
        int code;
        bool parsed = Int32.TryParse(requestTelemetry.ResponseCode, out code);
        if (!parsed) return;
        if (code >= 400 && code < 500)
        {
            // If we set the Success property, the SDK won't change it:
            requestTelemetry.Success = true;
            // Allow us to filter these requests in the portal:
            requestTelemetry.Context.Properties["Overridden400s"] = "true";
        }
        // else leave the SDK to set the Success property      
    }
  }
}
```

Then, add this initializer to AI either via ApplicationInsights.config or in code:

```
<ApplicationInsights>
  <TelemetryInitializers>
    <!-- Fully qualified type name, assembly name: -->
    <Add Type="MvcWebRole.Telemetry.MyTelemetryInitializer, MvcWebRole"/>
    ...
  </TelemetryInitializers>
</ApplicationInsights>

protected void Application_Start()
{
    // ...
    TelemetryConfiguration.Active.TelemetryInitializers
    .Add(new MyTelemetryInitializer());
}
```